# How to pass html directly to template

Tags: python, templates, bottle, sts-simple-templatesystem

I want to pass HTML directly as a parameter in `template()`.
I know I could do something like:

```
%for i in array:
  <a>{{i}}</a>
%end
```

but I need to pass it directly when I call template,
I tried replacing `&lt` and `&gt` with `< >` with javascript but that did not work. 
I want to do this:

```
{{results_of_i_in_array}}
```

and the loop will occur in my main rather than in the template,
I never found anyone asking the same question.
Note: this question is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357462/django-passing-html-string-to-template).

I am using bottle default templating system, thanks in advance.

Comment: check bottle documentation - maybe it has soemthing similar to `autoescape off` or `text|safe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bottle doc:

> You can start the expression with an exclamation mark to disable
>   escaping 
>       for that expression:
>
> ```
> >>> template('Hello {{name}}!', name='<b>World</b>')
> u'Hello &lt;b&gt;World&lt;/b&gt;!'
> >>> template('Hello {{!name}}!', name='<b>World</b>')
> u'Hello <b>World</b>!'
> ```