# bottle › template with rebase and/or include

Tags: python, templates, bottle

Need some advice to use rebase  and/or include.

For building a flexible concept with a variable menu system I need to insert a *'menuY.tpl'* template into different *'mainX.tpl'* pages.

Sounds easy but not only the pages need

```
   thisTemplate = template('mainX', keys)
```

but also the menus need changing menukeys

```
   thisMenu = template('menuY', menukeys)
```

How to define the different instructions?

python

```
@app.route('/doit')
def week():
   ...some code here to load keys etc ...
   thisTemplate = template('mainX', keys)
   return thisTemplate
```

*mainX.tpl*  with

```
    <body>
      % insert ('menuY', rv)
      <section class="container">
         <p>{{param1}}</p>
         some html code for the main page
      </section>
   </body>
```

*menuY.tpl*  with just html code for the menu code like this

```
   <div id="hambgMenu">
       <a href="/">Home - {{titleY}}</a>
       <a href="/week">{{titleZ}}</a>
   </div>
```

This will not work, at the *mainX.tpl* line with % insert python says:

```
   NameError: name 'insert' is not defined
```

Also how are the *variables* (titleY,titleZ) passed to that '*menuY*'? There is no reference for 'rv' with the coding above.

Comment: Isn't your mistake just that you mispelt `include` as `insert`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was described here [How to pass html directly to template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021763/how-to-pass-html-directly-to-template/42022159#42022159) ... very easy, just to add ! to the template reference.

I did some further steps just to have on Python:

```
@app.route('/doit')
def doit():
    page = insertTPL('mainX', keys, 'menuY', menukeys, 'menuTag')
    return page
```

.. with *menuTag* as declared as follows:

So   *mainX.tpl*   becomes

```
    <body>
      {{!menuTag}}
      <section class="container">
         <p>{{param1}}</p>
         some html code for the main page
      </section>
   </body>
```

The mentioned *insertTPL* python function has:

```
  def insertTPL(tpl, keys, menu, menukeys, menuTag):
      subtpl = template(menu, menukeys)
      rv = combineKeys(keys, {menuTag:subtpl}) # combine the menu code with other keys! 
      return template(tpl, rv)

  def combineKeys(rv1, rv2):
      try:
          keys = {key: value for (key, value) in (rv1.items() + rv2.items())}
      except:
          keys = rv1
      return keys
```